# Dynamically load Embedded Twitter Timeline

Tags: javascript, twitter, coffeescript

Twitter has great embedded timelines, however I can only seem to get the to work by copy-pasting the widget code twitter provide:

```
<a class="twitter-timeline" data-widget-id="SOME_WIDGET_ID">Tweets about XXXXX</a>
<script>!function(d,s,id){var js,fjs=d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];if(!d.getElementById(id)){js=d.createElement(s);js.id=id;js.src="//platform.twitter.com/widgets.js";fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js,fjs);}}(document,"script","twitter-wjs");</script>
```

Is there some way I can dynamically load an embedded timeline into a div based on a widget ID?

Answer (score 0):

There is:
https://plus.google.com/u/0/110804953626559077511/posts/j65ntqa5Qd3

I don't recommend it though. All Twitter would have to do is change one tiny thing in their widgets.js file and this will stop working.

Answer (score 0):

If you have the [`widgets.js`](http://platform.twitter.com/widgets.js) file, you can use the [`twttr.widgets.createTimeline()`](https://dev.twitter.com/docs/tfw-javascript) function to specify an element to create a timeline. Just set the username dynamically, and it should work.